# How to work knowing that I work in the most menial position compared to my classmates from college?

Tags: work-environment

I fall asleep every night and wake up and tell myself crap- I'm stuck doing this anti-intellectual things that none of my classmates have to do because they're a lot smarter than me,the person who grew up poor and only singled-majored, and they could learn things in less time than me and had way more fun during college and work less hard and earn more, and actually have friends today. They literally were trained to juggle multiple responsibilities since they were five because their parents drove them o extracurriculars everyday after school since they were five, and the latchkey poor kids were left at home and taught not responsibilities and rotted.

I keep going to work after a night of doing more intellectual things such as studying for the GRE or reading a book and I go to a job where it's high school or 8th grade graduate level of data entry, sending e-mails, flipping through filing cabinets, comparing two documents, admin assistant.

I went to college where everyone but me was a genius who double majored in something such as Economics and Political Science or Computer Science and some literature major where they're capable of writing 100 page essays every month so they're not some average liberal arts major and they grew up rich enough to do sports everyday after-school because their parents don't have to work. Believe it or not, but google has 20-22 year olds making 200,000 a year. They're those people, and doing intellectual things such as translating any idea into code or doing a Economics Phd or going to law school/ med school straight out of undergrad.

I have this STEM masters degree and I'm doing 8th grade level work and it's really infuriating.
TLDR: I wake up morning unexcited for work knowing that I'm doing trash work, living a trash life compared to the intellectuals of the world, what do I do? Couldn't find something better job.

Comment: I assume you have looked for other jobs. Where did that go wrong?

Comment: Most people I know only did a single major in school, including myself. What is it you would rather be doing? What barriers are stopping you from doing it?

Comment: So, you have a STEM master degree. What prevents you from getting a job as a regular engineer ? Is it because of the COVID economy in your country ? If yes, then keep applying for many jobs everyday, and networking with your ex-classmates/friends, and, one day, when the economy improves, you will eventually get your dream job.

Comment: Don't compare yourself to your "**highly successful**" friends because if they compare themselves to Einstein, Mozart, Chopin, Nobel prize winners, Bill Gates, Steve Jobs, Elon Musk, Jeff Bezos, etc... they will be just as disappointed at themselves as you are now. No matter how successful a person is, someone else will always be better than him/her. Just focus on doing your best and enjoy your life with your family.

Comment: @Job_September_2020  -  Very true.  There's always someone doing better than you however good you are.  Even at the top of the heap you'll be worried about who is coming up from below to take it away from you.

Comment: It sounds like you are going through some things. I recommend you discuss this situation with friends or family. And maybe even consider seeing a professional. I would just add that it's very possible they are not more intellectual, they just possess more easily transferable skills to the real work. I suspect you just need to find your niche.

Comment: This sounds like actual depression - which is a medical condition. This would do well to be taken to a medical professional and not to the web.

Answer (score 12):

> what do I do?

Stop comparing yourself to others. Work on achieving for yourself and boosting your self-esteem and self-confidence. You're not defined by your job or your ex classmates. You define yourself.

If you come from poverty through university. Then someone worked very hard and sacrificed a lot to get you through. Don't let them down by feeling sorry for yourself. Show the same strength of character that they did. Just work out what you really want and then go get it.

Success isn't always just about brains and privilege. For some it's all about guts and focus.

Comment: _"Success isn't always just about brains and privilege. For some it's all about guts and focus."_ Exactly, privileges can't compensate for determination, passion and commitment..

Comment: +1  "You're not defined by your job or your ex classmates" exactly this.  The best people I know are not the smartest or wealthiest, they are the ones with the greatest generosity of spirit.

Comment: Success is when I am living according to my values, not when comparing myself financially to others.

Answer (score 4):

"I went to college where everyone but me was a genius"

No, they were not. Genius is rare. Exceedingly rare. I met *one* at my university. One, maybe two, in my working life. Genius is less than one in 10,000. So no, what you are saying there is nonsense.

You should have a look at cognitive behavioural theory. Your problem seems to be that you don't see the world as it is. You are not surrounded by super humans. You are surrounded by people that you should have no problem competing with. What holds you back is your view of the world, and taking your view of the world as an excuse to make no progress.

Did you look for better jobs? Did you apply? What attitude did you apply with? "Everyone else is so much better than me" "In that case I'll hire anyone else". You have a masters degree, for heavens' sake. Be proud of it. Apply for jobs accordingly. Tell yourself and tell everyone else that you will make it.

Answer (score 0):

You live in the most materially developed and spiritually advantaged part of the word, during the century of man's greatest achievement. Even the most oppressed wage slave in an Amazon warehouse has a fantastically better life that almost every human who ever lived.

Opportunities to find happiness, and opportunities to provide happiness to others, lie in your path seven times seventy times a day. Unfortunately your day job is not a font of such opportunities; you will have to figure out where else to look.

(1) Extrinsic Rewards.

Instead of comparing yourself to your contemporaries who have more opportunities and privileges than you, compare yourself to the nine out of ten humans who ever lived on Earth who had no medicine, insufficient food, and an average life expectancy of 48 years.

(2) Intrinsic Rewards.

Of all the things that you could do, choose the one that you feel will provide the maximum permanent benefit to humanity at large. Use the trash job to finance your life while you dedicate yourself to what you know is really important.